# Почему после "говорят" поставлена запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

> Каждый из нас рано или поздно задается вопросом: что такое душа
>   человека? Говорят, нужно заглянуть в глаза и разглядеть душу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**ГОВОРЯТ**, вводное слово](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_139)

> Указывает на то, что говорящий опирается на информацию, услышанную ранее, на слухи.

Вводные слова выделяются запятыми. См.: [**ПУНКТУАЦИЯ ПРИ ВВОДНЫХ СЛОВАХ И СОЧЕТАНИЯХ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2).

Даже если предположить, что ***говорят*** не вводное слово, а сказуемое, то запятая всё равно была бы необходима, так как она бы разделяла два предложения, второе из которых: ***нужно заглянуть... и разглядеть...*** — безличное.

*[Они] говорят, нужно заглянуть в глаза и разглядеть душу.*